# Installing Ruby 1.9.3 or later on EC2 - Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm trying to deploy using chef on EC2. I'm using knife ec2 to bootstrap t1.micro with Ubuntu 12.04 and LAMP stack. I get following error while chef tries to install packages as per its role.

```
Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_service_rhel.rb
================================================================================


NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_service_rhel.rb:3
```

Apparently it is because ruby version on EC2 during bootstrap is 1.8.7 and it doesn't have the above mentioned method. I tried tens of pages around web to upgrade it to 1.9.3 or more but the problem persists in several ways. I see the old ruby version when I do sudo rubo -v but latest when I do ruby -v. The problem is same even when I do sudo after logging in as root on EC2. Any one faced this problem while trying to install with Chef ? Any pointers to install ruby where I will be able to see the udpate version after sudo will be helpful. I unsuccesfully spent a whole day trying to figure out a correct solution.

Comment: Consider using RVM, it is the preferred way.

Comment: I tried rvm method as well. That is when I get the problem of different version in sudo and root.

Answer (score 2):

Please **don't** use RVM as suggested in the comments. It is **not** the preferred way to install Chef. The preferred way to install Chef is using the Omnibus installer:

```
curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | bash
```

This will install Chef, an embedded Ruby, and all Chef's dependencies automatically for you.

Refs:

- http://www.getchef.com/chef/install/

Comment: What about the issue of needing Ruby 1.9.3+ for require_relative? The embedded version appears to be 1.8.7.

Comment: The embedded version is 1.9.3 and will soon be 2.1.

Comment: So it is... I didn't realize I was using https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/precise/current/precise-server-cloudimg-i386-vagrant-disk1.box. After I run the curl command above in my vagrantfile through an inline shell provisioner and ssh into the box I saw 1.8.7. In case it's helpful to any others if needed, I mitigated this by running another shell provisioner to build ruby 1.9.3 (like https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bartimaeus/2845824/raw/efd27688a72d7089fac6865021947ea812c7b31e/install-ruby.sh) after the curl chef install.